# Getting the value from a TinyMCE textarea

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have a news editor for my site with which I am using TinyMCE.  What I would like to be able to do is have a button (outside of the TinyMCE editor itself) that I can click to scan the textarea for any images, then list those images as options to use for a thumbnail image for said news article.

For an idea of what I mean, please see this link here: https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B05m73kzudwPNzUwZjkyNmItYjZkMy00NTdlLTlkNDctOGRhYThjMzNjNTM5&hl=en_US

My problem is that document.getElementById('NewsArticle').value is not returning anything when there is text in the textarea

The other potential problem is that whats shown in the textarea is not actual code, but images etc too so I wasn't sure it would even work in the first place, but since when the form is submitted the data[News][article] value is back into text, I thought there might be a chance.

If anyone knows how to get either the content or code for the tinyMCE textarea, or has a better solution, I'd be interested to hear

Comment: check this answer to transfer the values of tinymce to original textarea.https://stackoverflow.com/a/69883895/12910765

Answer (score 163, accepted):

TinyMce has [an api](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.getContent) for accessing content from the editor.

This code will grab the html from the active editor:

```
// Get the HTML contents of the currently active editor
tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();

// Get the raw contents of the currently active editor
tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent({format : 'raw'});

// Get content of a specific editor:
tinyMCE.get('content id').getContent()
```

Comment: Looks like the API location has changed: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/apis/tinymce.html.writer/#getContent

Answer (score 10):

Use below syntax, which will remove unwanted character from your input textarea....

```
(((tinyMCE.get('YourTextAreaId').getContent()).replace(/(&nbsp;)*/g, "")).replace(/(<p>)*/g, "")).replace(/<(\/)?p[^>]*>/g, "");
```

Comment: I would wrap that in a function and pass the text to it but +1 for the effort.

Answer (score 9):

Try

```
window.parent.tinymce.get('contentID').getContent();
```

For some reason, the stock-standard `tinymce.get()` call didn't work for me, so I tried this and it works. :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I have been struggling with multiple editors & your this code worked really well for me!!

Answer (score 4):

```
var temp = tinymce.get('textAreaName').save();
console.log(temp);
```

***OR***

```
var temp =tinymce.get('textAreaName').getContent();
console.log(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have something like

```
<form>
  <textarea id="myArea">Hello, World!</textarea>
</form>
```

you should simply add as follows

```
<form method="post">
  <textarea id="myArea" name="value">Hello, World!</textarea>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

and you can catch the data with PHP under myArea var.