# how to retrieve the value of TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, return-value

I have problems in 'textarea', I want to take the value of "TinyMCE" how can I take the value of "TinyMCE" with jquery

```
<td>
  <textarea id="body" name="body" rows="20" cols="50" class="mceEditor"><c:out value="${article.body}"/></textarea>
  <form:errors path="body" cssClass="fieldError"/>
</td>
```

this code after firebug

```
<table id="body_editor_tbl" class="mceLayout" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 341px; height: 303px;">
  <tbody id="">
    <tr class="mceFirst">
    <tr class="mceLast">
    <td class="mceIframeContainer mceFirst mceLast">
      <iframe id="body_editor_ifr" frameborder="0" src="javascript:""" style="width: 100%; height: 257px;">
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
        <html>
          <head xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
          <body id="tinymce" class="mceContentBody " spellcheck="false" dir="ltr">
            <br mce_bogus="1">
          </body>
        </html>
      </iframe>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

how I can retrieve the value of TinyMCE,
karenasaya want to issue a message when tinymce is of no value, and will be ignored if no value

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541782/getting-the-value-from-a-tinymce-textarea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the contents of a tinymce editor

```
$('#your_editor_id').tinymce().getContent());
```