# Laravel - get the textarea value from view within TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, tinymce

**My problem:**

Everything is appearing within the view as expected, but once the user has edited the text field, I want to then re-upload it to the database. However, within the Controller, I cannot `get` the text within the 'textarea'.

**Current HTML set up within my view is:**

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 
    array('updateReport', $report->first()->id), 'role'=>'form','id'=>'updateReport')) !!}

<textarea class="form-control" id="report" name="report" rows="15">
    {{ $report->first()->html }}</textarea>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-labeled btn-success" aria-hidden="true">
    <span class="btn-label">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></i></span> Update Report</button>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Javascript section to initialise the TinyMCE:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  tinymce.init({
    selector: '#report',
  menubar: false,
  browser_spellcheck: true,
  });
</script>
```

**I have tried:**

`Input::all() and Input::get('report')` - both return `null`.

How can I get the raw HTML that's newly edited and stored "behind the scenes", surely there must be a simple way?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't the provided `tinyMCE.getContent('#report');` return it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the value from a TinyMCE textarea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541782/getting-the-value-from-a-tinymce-textarea)

Comment: @camelCase, How would I return this though within my form, so I can access it within my controller please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's only one field to worry about, `tinymce.activeEditor.getContent()` should do the trick

Comment: How can I use this to return the text when I click `submit` please?

Comment: You could potentially intercept the form submit with javascript and write that value to a hidden field (or back to the original textarea). Alternatively, there are packages out there made for integrating tinyMCE with Laravel such as this one https://github.com/ktquez/laravel-tinymce

Comment: The above package that you recommended works as expected. Many thanks, @jmcgriz!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `setup` call back to bind a `change` event to the editor which will trigger a save.  This places the modified content back in the original `textarea` allowing you to post it to your script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  tinymce.init({
    selector: '#report',
    setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('change', function () {
            tinymce.triggerSave();
        });
    },
    menubar: false,
    browser_spellcheck: true
  });
</script>
```