# how to get value from inside a tinymce editor instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce-4

recently i'm working on this project where i have to create a working tagging system in tinymce editor. i used at.js and was able to capture keyboard press events but got stumped in getting the value out of the function involving a ajax call. The question is how can i get the values from a function as an array and pass it to the at script, which i don't know how to do it in javascript or jquery can anyone help me with this. the response i get from alert value is as follows:
`[{"readyState":4,"responseText":"\n\n{\"names\":\"Shikhar Bansal(bshikhar13131313@gmail.com),\"}","responseJSON":{"names":"Shikhar Bansal(bshikhar13131313@gmail.com),"},"status":200,"statusText":"OK"}]`"

the code i worked so far,

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea#wall_id_1',
  height: 300,
  theme: 'modern',
  resize: false,
  force_p_newlines: false,
  plugins: 'print preview powerpaste searchreplace autolink directionality advcode visualblocks visualchars fullscreen image link media template codesample table charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor toc insertdatetime advlist lists textcolor wordcount tinymcespellchecker a11ychecker imagetools mediaembed  linkchecker contextmenu colorpicker textpattern help',
  toolbar1: 'formatselect | bold italic strikethrough forecolor backcolor | link | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify  | numlist bullist outdent indent  | removeformat',
  image_advtab: true,
  templates: [
    { title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1' },
    { title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2' }
  ],
  content_css: [
    '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,400i',
    '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css'
  ],
  setup: function(editor) {
        editor.on('keyup', function(e) {
    /*      
            var eli= $(editor.contentDocument.activeElement).prop('innerHTML');

            var txt=$(eli+'p').html();
          var txt1=$(eli+'span').html();
          var regex=new RegExp(/@+([a-zA-z!._-]+)/g);
           var match= regex.exec(txt); 
     //console.log(match);
   // alert(match);
 var names=load_Ajax(match[1]);
 return names;*/
          if(e.keyCode == 13 && $(editor.contentDocument.activeElement).atwho('isSelecting'))
            return false;
        });
  return names;    
  },

  init_instance_callback: function(editor) {


    var name= editor.on("keyup",function(e){

            var eli= $(editor.contentDocument.activeElement).prop('innerHTML');

            var txt=$(eli+'p').html();
          var txt1=$(eli+'span').html();
          var regex=new RegExp(/@+([a-zA-z!._-]+)/g);
           var match= regex.exec(txt); 

     var results=new Array(); 
$.ajax({
           url : "jsdropdown.php",
   data : {"uname":match[1]},
   async: false,
   complete:function(res){
      results.push(res);
      //results=res;
     // alert(JSON.stringify(res));
    return res;
    },
    dataType: "html"
});



   alert(JSON.stringify(results));  
    }).responseJSON;



        $(editor.contentDocument.activeElement).atwho({at: "@", data: names});

  }

 });
```

i have attached a snippet its not perfect so please feel free to edit it(as i'm not good enough to edit it to working condition.)

```js
var names = ["Jacob", "Isabella", "Ethan", "Emma", "Michael", "Olivia", "Alexander", "Sophia", "William", "Ava", "Joshua", "Emily", "Daniel", "Madison", "Jayden", "Abigail", "Noah", "Chloe", "你好", "你你你", "jeremy"];
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea#wall_id_1',
  height: 300,
  theme: 'modern',
  resize: false,
  force_p_newlines: false,
  plugins: 'print preview powerpaste searchreplace autolink directionality advcode visualblocks visualchars fullscreen image link media template codesample table charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor toc insertdatetime advlist lists textcolor wordcount tinymcespellchecker a11ychecker imagetools mediaembed  linkchecker contextmenu colorpicker textpattern help',
  toolbar1: 'formatselect | bold italic strikethrough forecolor backcolor | link | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify  | numlist bullist outdent indent  | removeformat',
  image_advtab: true,
  templates: [{
      title: 'Test template 1',
      content: 'Test 1'
    },
    {
      title: 'Test template 2',
      content: 'Test 2'
    }
  ],
  content_css: [
    '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,400i',
    '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css'
  ],
  setup: function(editor) {
    editor.on('keyup', function(e) {
      /*      
            var eli= $(editor.contentDocument.activeElement).prop('innerHTML');
        
            var txt=$(eli+'p').html();
          var txt1=$(eli+'span').html();
          var regex=new RegExp(/@+([a-zA-z!._-]+)/g);
           var match= regex.exec(txt); 
     //console.log(match);
   // alert(match);
 var names=load_Ajax(match[1]);
 return names;*/
      if (e.keyCode == 13 && $(editor.contentDocument.activeElement).atwho('isSelecting'))
        return false;
    });
    return names;
  },

  init_instance_callback: function(editor) {


    var name = editor.on("keyup", function(e) {

      var eli = $(editor.contentDocument.activeElement).prop('innerHTML');

      var txt = $(eli + 'p').html();
      var txt1 = $(eli + 'span').html();
      var regex = new RegExp(/@+([a-zA-z!._-]+)/g);
      var match = regex.exec(txt);

      var results = [];
      $.ajax({
        url: "jsdropdown.php",
        data: {
          "uname": match[1]
        },
        async: false,
        complete: function(res) {
          results.push(res);
          //results=res;
          // alert(JSON.stringify(res));
          return res;
        },
        dataType: "html"
      });



      alert(JSON.stringify(results));
    }).responseJSON;



    $(editor.contentDocument.activeElement).atwho({
      at: "@",
      data: names
    });

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/at.js/1.5.4/css/jquery.atwho.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/caret/1.0.0/jquery.caret.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/at.js/1.5.4/js/jquery.atwho.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <div class='jumbotron'><input type='text' class='form-control title_s' name='status_title' placeholder='Title '><br>
    <textarea id='wall_id_1' class='update_session' placeholder='whats up'> 
            </textarea><br><button class="btn btn-warning btn btn-large btn-lg post-s"> Post</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: As per my understanding you need to get data of textarea having tinyMCE editor. You can refer existing answer link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541782/getting-the-value-from-a-tinymce-textarea#6541822

Comment: @PrasadWargad no i already am getting the value out of the text area. Actually i need to get the value out of the `editor.on(` function

Comment: Can you have any JSFiddle for this, so that giving solution will be little easier.

Comment: @PrasadWargad i have attached a imperfect snippet please feel free to edit it if you can

Comment: Please go through the http://jsfiddle.net/e8szo2yw/3/. In code given by you, ajax request gets triggered when HTML editor value gets changed. You are matching a pattern which starts with '@' then after lower/upper case A to Z. When user do not put '@' at start of text, then "match[1]" becomes null & throws a javascript error. If typed text in HTML editor starts with '@' then ajax request gets thrown properly & rest of the code gets executed. Please check details of regexp that you are matching.

Comment: thats the point @PrasadWargad i'm trying to create a tagging system here. up to the point of user presses @ it shouldn't fire thats how i intend it to happen. but the problem is i don't know how to fetch the ajax call returned value out of the `editor.on(` function and pass it as data in to the  `$(editor.contentDocument.activeElement).atwho({
      at: "@",
      data: <i want the ajax returned value here as a name>
    });`which is where i'm stumped i hope you got my problem.

Comment: Please go through updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/e8szo2yw/5/ where I had made few changes related to finding a string starting with "@" character. Now if string contains "@" character then only AJAX request gets sent & then after only ".atwho" function gets called up. When pressing "@" currently it's showing "TAGS" too. Just check for a word like "@re" it's showing "Jeremy". Please check fiddle, it might be useful or it will give you a little idea towards to your goal.

Comment: @PrasadWargad how do i bring that results variable trimmed enough to replace the names variable at the .atwho function is my question. is there a way to do it

Comment: I guess, they were coming out their. Popup with set of names is getting shown in Fiddle, from where you can choose which ever option you want. Can you please elaborate, what you mean to say.

Comment: @PrasadWargad i would like to replace the names array with the results variable(trimmed) as it outputs the name i want the names variable contains the name of what the atwho script author put in the script, but the ajax call i made outputs the name from database which is i want in the script to perform so my tagging sys can be complete if you want to know what output i get pl refer the main post.

Comment: @PrasadWargad are you there bro